# Can I have a lower version code at production from alpha testing channel

Tags: android, google-play, versioning, android-testing

I need to publish my application first at alpha testing channel at play developer console and then to production. Lets say that I publish the application at alpha with version code 1.0.0. After testing it, I need to publish updates of the application so I increase the version code to 1.0.1, 1.0.2, etc.

1. After I finish testing, can I upload a new apk to production with an initial version code 1.0.0? I don't want to promote the apk published at the alpha channel that will have an increased version code i.e. 1.0.5. Will that cause any issues?
2. Do you have any other recommendation how to handle this case?

Thanks,

Lupe

Comment: Instead of publishing 1.0.0 to Alpha just publish 0.9.0 to alpha, and once you're done with all the updates increase the version code to 1.0.0. Do you think that would work?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In Android, application versioning consists of two things.

> 1. android:versionCode -  An integer value that represents the version of the application code, relative to other versions.
> 2. android:versionName — A string value that represents the release version of the application code, as it should be shown to users.

What is **visible** to the users is the **second one**. So you can have for example a version in alpha where `android:versionName` is `"1.0.0"` and `android:versionCode` is `1` (integer), then do your testing and fixes and when you are ready to deploy in production keep `android:versionName` to `"1.0.0"` but have `android:versionCode` increased by `1` from the last value it had in alpha, e.g. `android:versionName="1.0.0"`, `android:versionCode=5` (the production is the 5th update from your initial aplha deploy). Of course you can change `"1.0.0"` to whatever you like, you can lower it too e.g. `"0.9.0"`, it's `android:versionCode` that always should be incremented by `1`.

You can read more here: [Versioning Your Applications](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html)

Comment: I'm my case, I have a production app with version code 9. But I uploaded an alpha app with version code 17(never worried about that until now). What happens if I publish as production with version code 10? I don't want to publish my app as v18, but i can't exclude this damn v17 alpha from history. Never tought that would give me headaches

Answer (score 2):

Version codes need only to be unique. As per document system does not enforce that new apk should have a greater version code.

Though a device, having installed an apk with a higher version code (17 in your case) will neither get update notification from play store nor play store will show that an update is available, because apk has a lower version code (10 in your case). It does not matter that v10 is uploaded after v17.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! Just yesterday I had `versionCode` 701 in the Alpha lane and wanted to publish a Beta from a different branch. The Alpha includes some features that are only available to our team, and the beta is a public Beta that doesn't have all the Alpha features merged in yet.

I hadn't used `versionCode` 700 yet, so I pushed that to the beta lane and it was accepted by the play store.

So, now, `versionCode` 700 is available for download to Beta testers, while `versionCode` 701 is in Alpha, and the Alpha version (701) was uploaded BEFORE the Beta version (700).

It seems like what matters is if the `versionCode` has been used yet. Hopefully that helps!